# What is the shortest regular expression that accepts anything except for the three characters: |, ^ and ~ (a pipe, a caret and a tilde)?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a regex but it is very big. I specify the set of chars that I allow.
That makes it big regex expression. Will it be simpler if I can specify the opposite i.e. just specify what chars I won't accept?

```
^[^\|\^~]*$
```

But it is not working. Any clue?

Comment: I totally misunderstood your question as the question title is incomprehensible due to it containing the **digit 3** instead of the literal **three**! It would have been better if it was asked like: *What is the shortest regular expression that accepts anything except for the three characters |, ^ and ~ (a pipe, a caret and a tilde)?*.

Comment: @Alan You can edit the question :)

Comment: marcog: True. Edited now. I just wanted the poster to understand the ambiguity. :-)

Comment: I edited as per comment from from Alan. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches strings that do not contain those three characters anywhere:

```
^[^|^~]*$
```

While this matches all strings that contain any of those three anywhere:

```
[|^~]
```

The two patterns are equivalent, so you could either use the first one, or use the second one with negation.

Comment: While your conclusion is correct under certain circumstances (that you could use either), saying they are equivalent is incorrect. But the conclusion is also incorrect if you want to nest it in a larger regular expression.

Comment: @marcog: It doesn't make sense to be embed it in a larger pattern, because then an earlier portion of the pattern could have consumed the forbidden characters such that the later portion would miss it. You could avoid this by embedding a leading `(?=^[^|~]*$)` at the start, which doesn’t consume anything but makes sure the string is free of the forbidden code points. If the problem were specified differently, I would have responded differently.

Comment: @marcog: Assume these three settings: `$badchars = '^|~'; $all_good = qr/^[^$badchars]*$/; $some_bad = qr/[$badchars]/;`. Now the test `/$all_good/` means exactly the same thing as the negated `! /$some_bad/` means. Similarly, `/$some_bad/` means the same as the negated `! /$all_good/` means. **Therefore** they *are* equivalent, in that you can always use either the one or else the other one negated to effect the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't escape `|` or `~` within `[]`. Use `^[^|^~]*$`.

```
>>> re.match(r'^[^|^~]*$', 'abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2dbc4a8>
>>> re.match(r'^[^|^~]*$', '^')
>>> re.match(r'^[^|^~]*$', '|')
>>> re.match(r'^[^|^~]*$', '~')
```

i.e. the first example matches, the other three fail as required.